# Ember - promise array

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have my controller, records is a computed property. On `orderBy` or `page` change my app shuold perform a new call.
This controller works perfectly:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  ...
  records: function() {
    return this.store.find("record", {
        page: this.get("page"),
        page_size: this.get("pageSize"),
        order_by: this.get("orderBy")
    })
  }.property("key", "orderBy", "page"),
})
```

But if I want to show an hourglass during the request:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  ...
  records: function() {
    this.showHourglass();
    return this.store.find("record", {
        page: this.get("page"),
        page_size: this.get("pageSize"),
        order_by: this.get("orderBy")
    }).then(function(records) {
      this.hideHourglass();
      return records;
    })
  }.property("key", "orderBy", "page"),
})
```

I got this error:
`Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed {_id: 59, _label: undefined, _state: undefined, _result: undefined, _subscribers: }`

How can I solve this?
Thanks

EDIT:
In my template there is a loop over the property:

```
{{#each records}}
    ...
{{/each}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is becuase `this.store.find("record")` returns an ArrayPromise. but because you are chaining a new `.then` the returned value is just a regular promise, which cannot be iterated upon.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  ...
  records: function() {
    this.showHourglass();
    var promiseArray = this.store.find("record", {
        page: this.get("page"),
        page_size: this.get("pageSize"),
        order_by: this.get("orderBy")
    })

    promiseArray.then(function(records) {
      this.hideHourglass();
    })

    return promiseArray;
  }.property("key", "orderBy", "page"),
})
```